# Google Maps VR in Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view, google-cardboard

I have an Android application with a map at the moment.

The native Google Maps application has a button that appears in street view, and when double tapped, it converts street view to VR mode. More specifically, it splits the street view in two for a separate image for each eye, to be used with Google cardboard. It then also tracks device movements and adjusts the FOV accordingly.

I'm building my own app, and would like to use this VR feature of maps in my own application.

One thought I have is to load two street view images immediately adjacent to each other, and then update the FOV by reading the device sensors.

I can see this being slow as my implementation is not likely to be as snappy as Googles.

Is there a way to use Google's own VR mode in a native app?

If not, what would you suggest doing to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I think you can try the `Cardboard SDK for Android`:The Cardboard project aims at developing inexpensive virtual reality (VR) tools to allow everyone to enjoy VR in a simple, fun, and natural way. The Cardboard SDK for Android enables developers familiar with OpenGL to quickly start creating VR applications. For more details, please refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/?hl=en).